# BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray causing Grow Heap (frag case)

Tags: c#, android, bitmap, xamarin, arrays

I am developing an Android app in Xamarin. I am having problems with generating an image from a bytestream. BitmapFactory (which seems to be the most popular solution), is causing huge allocation problems - Grow Heap.

```
        ConnectToDb connect = new ConnectToDb ();
        byte[] arr = connect.SelectImgByte(3,"Thea");

        BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.InJustDecodeBounds = true;
        bmp = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray (arr, 0, arr.Length/*,options*/);
        _imageView.SetImageBitmap (bmp);
```

Above is the method where BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray is being called. It works fine, the image is displayed. But it is slow and causes these "Warnings".

```
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #6
[dalvikvm-heap] Grow heap (frag case) to 22.596MB for 1997584-byte allocation
[Choreographer] Skipped 129 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
[dalvikvm-heap] Grow heap (frag case) to 20.755MB for 1997584-byte allocation
[dalvikvm-heap] Grow heap (frag case) to 22.735MB for 1997584-byte allocation
[dalvikvm-heap] Grow heap (frag case) to 24.710MB for 1997584-byte allocation
```

For everytime the method is called, Grow Heap error appears. As you can see i have loaded an image to an imageview 4 times there. 
So, i was wondering if anyone had the same problem as me? I tried for many hours to solve the problem, by looking in here (and else where) but i could not find a solution. 
Keep in mind i am writing the application in Xamarin (c# language - using Android library).

Sorry for the lousy links, but i don't have enough cred to upload images here yet :)

Comment: Please include your code in the post rather than linking to pictures of it, the links may die in future an it also makes the post harder to read.

Comment: hi i need 10 or more in reputation so i cannot do it now. I am a total newbie in here, so my reputation is still 1 :)

Comment: You can post text in your question then mark it as code and it will be formatted correctly, this does not require any reputation points.

Comment: @TheaRasmussen you want to download your image or are you using Drawable image to display????

Comment: Thanks for the hint! As you can see i am adding the image to an ImageView - So i am using a drawable image to display i guess.

Comment: @TheaRasmussen but right now you are downloading or getting it from Drawable?

Comment: Ah misunderstood. I am getting the byte stream (image byte stream) from a database. My images is not stored in drawable.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I see is that you use `InJustDecodeBounds`, which usually is used to get the width and height of the image like so:

```
var options = new BitmapFactory.Options {
    InJustDecodeBounds = true,
};
using (var derp = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, 
    Resource.Id.myimage, options)) { }

var imageHeight = options.OutHeight;
var imageWidth  = options.OutWidth;
```

This is generally used to get the aspect ratio of the image, before scaling it down, instead of loading a huge image into the memory.

If you take a look at the [docs about loading large bitmaps efficiently](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/resources/general/load_large_bitmaps_efficiently/) in the Xamarin documentation you will find that they use it for just that.

Then they make sure to load the `Bitmap` in a `using` statement and assign it to the `ImageView` like this:

```
using(var bmp = DecodeBitmap(some args))
    imageView.SetImageBitmap(bmp);
```

In cases where you don't need the `Bitmap` afterwards you can call `Recycle()` on it, which tells the Java Runtime to get rid of it:

```
using(var bmp = DecodeBitmap(some args)) {
    imageView.SetImageBitmap(bmp);
    bmp.Recycle();
}
```

So you need to do something similar, probably also with your `byte` array as it contains all the pixels for the image.

So using the pattern in the docs you could do something like this:

```
byte[] arr = connect.SelectImgByte(3,"Thea");

using(var bmp = DecodeSampledBitmapFromArray(arr, scaledWidth, scaledHeight)) {
    _imageView.SetImageBitmap(bmp);
    bmp.Recycle();
}

public static int CalculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight)
{
    // Raw height and width of image
    var height = (float)options.OutHeight;
    var width = (float)options.OutWidth;
    var inSampleSize = 1D;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth)
    {
        inSampleSize = width > height
                            ? height/reqHeight
                            : width/reqWidth;
    }

    return (int) inSampleSize;
}

public static Bitmap DecodeSampledBitmapFromArray(byte[] pixels, int reqWidth, int reqHeight)
{
    var options = new BitmapFactory.Options {
        InJustDecodeBounds = true,
    };
    using (var dispose = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(arr, 0, arr.Length, options)) { }

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.InSampleSize = CalculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.InJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(arr, 0, arr.Length, options);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Cheesebaron. The image i want to create is from a byte stream, and it is not found in resources (so i cant use Decoderesources). The structure of your method calls i am already using when i am taking the picture and saving it. There i am scaling it down as well. But it is not the structure that gives problems, it is when i am using this method BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray. If i used your code, only modified with DecodeByteArray then i would get even more Grow Heap errors since the method DecodeByteArray would be called twice (in DecodeSampledBitmapFromArray).